# ImportError: No module named pyimagesearch.facedetector

Tags: opencv

> #Error in importing the module: #
>
> ```
> from __future__ import print_function
> from pyimagesearch.facedetector import FaceDetector
> import argparse
> import cv2
> ```

Comment: Hello! Welcome to *StackOverflow*. Please read through [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question on SO. Also, please refer [how to give an example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to know what details to provide while asking a question.

Comment: ensure that `pyimagesearch.py` file is in the same folder as the script you are running

Answer (score 0):

pyimagesearch doesn't exist on PYPI . If it's a project then  You need to install manually.